# Do Both Ends Need LACP Configured for LACP to work?

Tags: networking, bonding, lacp

We are trying to use link aggregation for some our experiments. So, we want to ask - If we have created link aggregation group with several ports on our switch do we have to create link aggreagation group on the other end, or we can simply plug in cables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both ends need it setup right.